# Object doesn't support property or method 'propAttr' on edge and IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have the following code

```
$('#btnApprove').propAttr('hidden',$('#status').val()!='W');
```

this works on all other browsers except microsoft edge and IE10

any solution, i tried adding
 `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` b
but didn't work. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Its either `.prop()` or `.attr()`, Do you have one of custom method `propAttr()`?

Comment: use `.prop()` in place of `propAttr()`. There is no function like `propAttr`.

Comment: jquery.ui has propAttr()

Comment: @MasterYi What is your goal ? You want to set a value on hidden input field ?

Comment: @Eriks yes, $('#btnApprove').prop('hidden',$('#status').val()!='W'); will this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it`s an input field

```
$('#btnApprove').val($('#status').val()!='W')
```

if you want to target type hidden field

```
$('#btnApprove[type="hidden"]').val($('#status').val()!='W')
```

Comment: $('#btnApprove[type="hidden"]').val($('#status').val()!='W') sovled the problem for edge will test other browsers but thanks !